# How to query count over 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a sql query that shows how often two teams have played against each other.

```
Id | Team1 | Team2 | Date 
1  |   A   |   B   | 25/5/11
2  |   B   |   A   | 26/5/11
3  |   A   |   C   | 27/5/11
4  |   C   |   B   | 28/5/11
5  |   A   |   B   | 28/5/11
```

result should be:

```
A vs B => 3
A vs C => 1
C vs B => 1
```

Counting A-B and B-A as different is an easy query. But I can't get them to be counted together.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Team names can be anything. I used A and B to write it more quickly.

Comment: is there a number that represents each team? ie from a teams table?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySql for my live database in this case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT Team1, Team2, SUM(num) FROM (
   SELECT Team1, Team2, COUNT(*) num
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY Team1, Team2
  UNION ALL
   SELECT Team2, Team1, COUNT(*) num
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY Team2, Team1
) combined
WHERE Team1 < Team2
GROUP BY Team1, Team2
```

Edit: Updated to reverse teams when necessary.

Note: This will run a lot faster than the versions using CASE you have been given in other answers because it will make full use of indexes.

Edit2: Moved the where to be even faster with indexes.

Comment: That will not give the right result.  There is a distinction between `A -> B` and `B -> A` in that query.  The OP is looking for A vs B to be combined with B vs A.

Comment: The table could grow pretty large... So use of indexes is probably needed... Thanks..

Comment: @Sorskoot Put in two indexes: on Team1, Team2 and a second index on Team2, Team1

Comment: I edited it to be even faster with the indexes. The `where` is actually optional - if you leave it out you'll get each grouping twice - this can be helpful since you'll only need to search the `Team1` column for a specific team instead of checking both columns for that team.

Comment: @Ariel - I think you put some unnecessary burden on the server. Take a look at my post and check the part labeled "Style 4". Based on the execution plan, that should be about 60% faster.

Comment: @leoinfo that's only faster because you have so little data. You are forcing the database to actually sort, group and count each row. With mine it just has to go in the index, and directly get the number of identical leafs in the index, it doesn't need to actually count them, it doesn't need to sort or group them either - just pull it right from the index.

Answer (score 6):

I've used a sub-query to reorder the teams before grouping.

```
SELECT first_team, second_team, count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2 END AS first_team,
        CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team2 ELSE Team1 END AS second_team
    FROM table
) a
GROUP BY first_team, second_team;
```

Comment: This will work, but it doesn't use indexes at all, so if you have a lot of teams use my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN Team1<Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2) Team1,
  (CASE WHEN Team1>Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2) Team2,
  COUNT(*)  cnt
FROM <table> 
GROUP BY 
  (CASE WHEN Team1<Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2) Team1,
  (CASE WHEN Team1>Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2) Team2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways of achieving your goal:

```
SELECT Teams, Games = COUNT(*) FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    Teams = CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2 END + ' vs ' +
            CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team2 ELSE Team1 END
  FROM MY_TABLE 
) AS T
GROUP BY Teams
```

OR, if you use SQL 2005/2008

```
;WITH T AS (
  SELECT 
    Teams = CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2 END + ' vs ' +
            CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team2 ELSE Team1 END
  FROM MY_TABLE 
)
SELECT Teams, Games = COUNT(*) FROM T GROUP BY Teams
```

Both of the above will give you the same result

```
/*
Teams     Games
-------|------
A vs B  3
A vs C  1
B vs C  1
*/
```

**Here is a script that you can play with:**

```
/* TEST DATA */
DECLARE @t AS TABLE ( ID INT, Team1 CHAR(1), Team2 CHAR(1), playdate [DATETIME] )
INSERT INTO @t (Team1 , Team2 , playdate)
          SELECT 'A' , 'B', '20110525'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B' , 'A', '20110526'    
UNION ALL SELECT 'A' , 'C', '20110527'    
UNION ALL SELECT 'C' , 'B', '20110528'    
UNION ALL SELECT 'A' , 'B', '20110528'    


/* STYLE 1 */    
;WITH T AS (
  SELECT 
    Teams = CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2 END + ' vs ' +
            CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team2 ELSE Team1 END
  FROM @t 
)
SELECT Teams, Games = COUNT(*) FROM T GROUP BY Teams

/* STYLE 2 */
SELECT Teams, Games = COUNT(*) FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    Teams = CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2 END + ' vs ' +
            CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team2 ELSE Team1 END
  FROM @t 
) AS T
GROUP BY Teams
```

/* OR , use this to just switch the columns */

```
/* STYLE 3 */    
;WITH T AS (
  SELECT 
      Team1 = CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2 END 
    , Team2 = CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team2 ELSE Team1 END
  FROM @t 
)
SELECT Team1 , Team2, Games = COUNT(*) FROM T GROUP BY Team1 , Team2

/* STYLE 4 */
SELECT Team1 , Team2, Games = COUNT(*) FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      Team1 = CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2 END 
    , Team2 = CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team2 ELSE Team1 END
  FROM @t 
) AS T
GROUP BY Team1 , Team2
```